# orderBy created_at on many-to-many relationship laravel and eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to know how can I use an orderby on created_at on pivot table.

Currently I have this :

- users
- events
- subscriptions [user_id, event_id, created_at, updated_at]

I would like to have all users subscriptions on specific event id :

```
return $this->user
    ->with('subscriptions')
    ->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) use ($eventId) {
        $query->where('events.id', $eventId)
              ->orderBy('subscriptions.created_at', 'ASC');
    })
    ->paginate(5);
```

I have all users attach on a specific event but the orderBy doesn't work.
I would like to use the whereHas and no the join method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should order on the with clause, like so:

```
return $this->user
    ->with([
        'subscriptions' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) use ($eventId) {
        $query->where('events.id', $eventId);
    })
    ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nuno for your answer. Same result, I don't see the result with orderBy apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this helps you my friend :

```
return $this->user
    ->with(['subscriptions' => function ($query) use ($eventId) {
        $query->where('event_id', $eventId)
              ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
    }])
    ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thank you @Marwane for your answer. I have an error : "mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given"

Comment: @JérémieChazelle, could you please try the edited response?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the hasManyThrough option. This will find all events that are intermediate of the subscriptions pertaining to the user.

```
User extends Model{
    public function ScopeEvents()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Event::class, Subscription::class);
    }
}

UserController extends Controller{
    public function listEvents(Request $request, User $user){
        $event_id = $request->get('event_id');
        return $user->events()->where('event_id',$event_id)
               ->orderBy('subscriptions.created_at','ASC')->paginate(5);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to get what you want:

- `join()`

```php
        return $this->user
            ->with('subscriptions')
            ->has('subscriptions')
            ->join('subscriptions', function ($join) use ($request) {
                $join->on('subscriptions.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
            })
            ->select('users.*', 'subscriptions.created_at as subscriptions_created_at')
            ->orderBy('subscriptions_created_at', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: code fixed                  .                       .            .

Answer (score 0):

`with()` uses eager loading, which turns query into multiple queries. You can try this.

```
return $this->user->join('subscriptions', function ($join) use ($eventId) {
                $join->on('subscriptions.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                $join->where('events.id', $eventId)
            })
            ->select('users.*', 'subscriptions.*')
            ->orderBy('subscriptions.created_at', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(25);
```